# Highcharts shared tooltip for line series and scatter plot not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have a highchart with a couple of line series and a scatter plot and I have set the shared tooltip property to true as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tpo4caoz/. I see that the line series are having a shared tool tip but the scatter plot is having a separate tooltip for itself.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                     'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            type: 'scatter'

        }, {
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        },{
            data: [210.4, 190.1, 90.6, 50.4, 20.9, 70.5, 105.4, 120.2, 140.0, 170.0, 130.6, 140.5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the existing issue in Highcharts issue tracker

> Part of the issue is that shared tooltip shouldn't work on scatter
>   series at all, because they are not sorted and laid out in increasing
>   X order. This should be noted in the docs([link](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1431)).

Answer (score 5):

you could try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/8qt0d4h0/

The new highcharts can not shared tooltip in pie/scatter/flag,
so you could handle the scatter as spline , and set the lineWidth equal and set states hover equal 0 too.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                     'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            type: 'spline',
            "lineWidth": 0,
                        "marker": {
              "enabled": "true",
              "states": {
                "hover": {
                  "enabled": "true"
                }
              },
              "radius": 5
            },
          "states": {
            "hover": {
              "lineWidthPlus": 0
            }
          },
        }, {
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
        },{
            data: [210.4, 190.1, 90.6, 50.4, 20.9, 70.5, 105.4, 120.2, 140.0, 170.0, 130.6, 140.5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line of code:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.scatter.prototype.noSharedTooltip = false;
```

It disables Hicharts default setting which disables scatter plots from being included in shared/split tooltips. This way you do not have to use spline like others suggest, which cant lead to problems such as tooltip following the spline line.

Answer (score 2):

According highcharts api http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared tooltip shared works only for ordered data and not for pie, scatter, flags etc.